# Turning an absolute value of a polynomial into a piece wise

Tags: polynomials, roots, absolute-value, piecewise-continuity

Express the following equation as a piecewise: f(x)= |x^2 -4x+3|
Ok so I know f(x)= |(x-1)(x-3)| therefore the piece wise "splits" at x=1 and x=3. However, I am confused as to which intervals I would make f(x) positive or negative. Is there a rule for figuring this out?

Comment: First, maybe $f(x)$ should have been $|x^2-4x+3|$. Second, since $f(x)$ is an absolute value, it is non-negative on every interval. Do you want to get rid of the absolute values?

Comment: Yes, I wish to turn it into a piecewise function. But am confused as how to go about doing that since inside the absolute value there are 2 zeroes suggesting that there are 3 intervals for the piecewise. I do not know how to take it further from this. Please help

Comment: $f(x)$ can not be turned into a piecewise function, since it is a polyonymal of degree $2$. You can check that $f(x)=(x-1)(x-3)$ for $x\geq 3$, that $f(x)=(x-1)(x-3)$ for $x\leq 1$ and $f(x)=-(x-1)(x-3)$ for $1\leq x\leq 3.$

Comment: Ok so you just turned it into a piecewise, but state that f(x) cannot be turned into a piecewise function? Graphically, your answer matches perfectly however. One last thing, how were you able to determine that only the interval [1,3] is -f(x) whilst intervals (negative infinite,1)U(3,positive infinite) are both f(x)?

Comment: Note that $|x|=x$ for $x\geq 0$ and $|x|=-x$ for $x\leq 0$. So $f(x)=|x-1|~|x-3|$ and work separately for $|x-1|$ and $|x-3|$. We have $|x-1|=x-1$ for $x\geq 1$ and $|x-1|=-(x-1)$ for $x\leq 1$ (work the same way for $|x-3|$).

Comment: WHOA I did not know you can express f(x) that way, from all my googling and asking people up to this point you were the only one that showed me u can "break" the absolute value into two. This makes more sense analytically, thank you sir.

Comment: Does this also apply in cases such as f(x)=|(x-1)(x-3)(x-4)|=|x-1| |x-3| |x-4|
?

Comment: Of course, it is a basic property of absolute value that $|ab|=|a|~|b|$ for all $a,~b$ and more generally, $|a_1a_2\ldots a_n|=|a_1|~|a_2|\ldots |a_n|$ for all reals $a_1,~a_2,\ldots,a_n.$

Comment: @NikolaosSkout Why can $f(x)$ not be expressed as a piecewise function?

Comment: I thought you wanted to express it as a piecewise linear, my mistake. Piecewisely, the way you can express it is as in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally $|x|=\left \{\begin {array}{ll}
x,~x\geq 0\\
-x,~x\leq 0\\
\end{array}
\right..~~$ So $$|x-1|=\left \{\begin {array}{ll}
x-1,~x\geq 1\\
-(x-1),~x\leq 1\\
\end{array}
\right.,~~|x-3|=\left \{\begin {array}{ll}
x-3,~x\geq 3\\
-(x-3),~x\leq 3\\
\end{array}
\right.$$ and

$$f(x)=|x-1|~|x-3|=\left \{\begin {array}{ll}
(x-1)(x-3),~x\geq 3\\
-(x-1)(x-3),~1\leq x\leq 3\\
(x-1)(x-3),~x\leq 1\\
\end{array}
\right..$$